# What does "rabbitmq_rejected_total" metric mean?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, metrics, spring-amqp, micrometer

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring AMQP. If I call `/prometheus` I get all metrics including `rabbitmq_rejected_total`. What does `rabbitmq_rejected_total` mean?

**Output**

```
[...]
# HELP rabbitmq_rejected_total  
# TYPE rabbitmq_rejected_total counter
rabbitmq_rejected_total{application="test-service",name="rabbit",} 0.0
[...]
```

**Question**

Does `rabbitmq_rejected_total` mean rejected and requeued ([`ImmediateRequeueAmqpException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/ImmediateRequeueAmqpException.html))? Or, does it mean rejected and not requeued ([`AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.html))?

See also [Negative Acknowledgements](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html):

> The AMQP 0-9-1 specification defines the `basic.reject` method that allows clients to reject individual, delivered messages, instructing the broker to either discard them or requeue them.

**Research**

I read [Spring AMQP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/), but I could not find any documentation about metrics.

I read [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.rabbitmq), but I could not find any documentation about this metric.

Comment: yeah, they are aware of this https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/issues/147

Answer (score 1):

The only metrics maintained by Spring AMQP are listener metrics

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer

i.e. how your listener performs when processing messages.

Metrics maintained by the RabbitMQ amqp-client are described here https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2018/04/rabbitmq-java-client-metrics-with-micrometer-and-datadog/

If you have questions about those metrics, I suggest you ask on the rabbitmq-users Google group.

My guess is this one is a count of how many messages were rejected (in Spring AMQP terms, when the listener throws an exception). Rejected messages may be requeued and redelivered, or discarded (optionally being sent to a DLQ).